# ScrollView child element measure always returning frameOffsetY = 0

Tags: listview, react-native

I'd like to use the `scrollTo` method of a `ScrollView`, to scroll to the element that is pressed.

Each child in the `ScrollView` has a `ref` and the measure is triggered with the `onLayout` prop, having `offsetY` on the state is enough to trigger the scroll correctly.

However the value returned on `this.componentRef.measure` for the `frameOffsetY` is always 0, so it always scrolls to the beginning of the ScrollView.

Below the code of the child components

```
  measureOffset() {
    this.componentRef.measure(
      (frameOffsetX, frameOffsetY, width, height, pageOffsetX, pageOffsetY) => {
        console.log(frameOffsetX, frameOffsetY, width, height, pageOffsetX, pageOffsetY);
        this.setState({ offsetY: frameOffsetY });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        ref={ref => this.componentRef = ref}
        style={{ opacity: 1, flex: 1 }}
        onLayout={() => this.measureOffset()}
      >
      ...
      </View>
    );
 }
```

The parent component is a ScrollView

```
  renderBuses() {
    return this.props.buses.map(bus =>
      <BusDetail 
        key={bus.reg_code} 
        bus={bus} 
        scrollTo={y => ScrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y })}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#e6e6e6' }}>
        <ScrollView 
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={ref => ScrollViewRef = ref}
        >
          {this.renderBuses()}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it's a bug of React Native.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that these measurements are not available until after the rendering has been completed in native. If you need the measurements as soon as possible, consider using the onLayout prop instead.

see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)

onLayout will be called when initialized, call measure here will not get the actual measurements.

there is an argument of onLayout function, use like this

```
onLayout={(e)=>{
  let obj = e.nativeEvent.layout;
  console.log(obj.width);
  console.log(obj.height);
}
```